# Calling form from another website

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a form which lets the user input 4 fields. What i'd like to know is if it possible to fill and submit a form on a totally separate website with the data that the user previously submitted using the form. If so, how can i do it?

Comment: Why can't you show this form in an iframe instead?

Comment: Let's say that i get the form input from website A. I get the input and i store it somewhere. Website B has the form that i want to automatically fill and submit. I have access to website B source of course but i was asked not to modify it so i wouldn't know how to use an iframe in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with direct HTTP post or get requests if the form doesn't have a security mechanism like CSRF tokens. Browsers won't allow users to do that with AJAX if the target website doesn't allow it (Target website is supposed to set a specific header to indicate whether the cross domain requests via AJAX is allowed).

If you want to submit it as soon as the user submits it, just recreate the form with html anywhere you want with the fields. The target url should be the absolute URL.

If you want to submit it later, You can save the submission data in a database and use "cURL" to submit it later with PHP. (more details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php))